# Custom "rubber band" view in Sproutcore

Tags: sproutcore

I'm scratching a long time itch and have started coding a simple 
browser-based image editor in Sproutcore.

70% of my image editing needs consist of cropping pictures. For the 
task of selecting which part of the image should remain visible, I 
would like to use the interface every image editor uses: the rubber 
band (?) selection box.

[image]

I'm pretty new to SC and I'm not sure how to go about implementing this. Is there a component available for what I want to do or will I need to write my own?

If I do need to write my own how would I go about doing it? Should I extend SC.ImageView and store the position of the selection box in there?

Thanks.

Comment: I think "marquee" is sometimes used to refer to those boxes. I'm interested in how to do rectangular area-select myself...